# DEPRECATED - Bookmark users - Fetch the list of users that bookmarked a question on any Stack Exchange website

Tags: script, users

**This userscript no longer works because [Stack Exchange has replaced bookmarks with "saves" in October 2022](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382019/bookmarks-have-evolved-into-saves). Saves are private and so can't be queried via the Stack Exchange Data Explorer.**

[image: GitHub Repo stars]
[image: current version]
[image: MIT license]
[image: Install this userscript]

Userscript to fetch the list of users that bookmarked a question on any Stack Exchange website.

This script uses the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) to fetch the list of users and augments this with user information from the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/).

Simply click the person icon below the bookmark icon to open the list. Note that the icon is only visible when there is at least one bookmark. Bookmarking users are listed in the order in which they created their bookmarks, newest to oldest.

### Screenshot

[image: screenshot]

### License

This script is [MIT licensed](https://github.com/mjpieters/SO-userscripts/blob/main/LICENSE).

### Issues and suggestions

[image: GitHub issues]
[image: GitHub pull requests]

Feature requests and bug reports are most welcome, please use the [GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/mjpieters/SO-userscripts/issues?q=is:issue+is%3Aopen+label:bookmark-users). Issues with accompanying [pull requests](https://github.com/mjpieters/SO-userscripts/pulls?q=is:pr+is%3Aopen+label:bookmark-users) are even more awesome!